# Weblogic slows down with exception

Tags: weblogic

I'm using weblogic 12.2.1.4 as queue manager and my Java application is connected to it. After weeks the Java applications slows down and reponds very slowly which I have to restart the weblogic service to go back to normal.
Its been a while that I see the following exception in my weblogic log.
I have searched for this exception in several forums and I found nothing.

```
 java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
        at weblogic.socket.NIOOutputStream.convertToSocketException(NIOOutputStream.java:250)
        at weblogic.socket.NIOOutputStream.access$600(NIOOutputStream.java:33)
        at weblogic.socket.NIOOutputStream$BlockingWriter.flush(NIOOutputStream.java:482)
        at weblogic.socket.NIOOutputStream$BlockingWriter.write(NIOOutputStream.java:334)
        at weblogic.socket.NIOOutputStream.write(NIOOutputStream.java:241)
Caused By: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractSelectableChannel.register(AbstractSelectableChannel.java:197)
        at java.nio.channels.SelectableChannel.register(SelectableChannel.java:280)
        at weblogic.socket.NIOOutputStream$BlockingWriter.flush(NIOOutputStream.java:467)
        at weblogic.socket.NIOOutputStream$BlockingWriter.write(NIOOutputStream.java:334)
        at weblogic.socket.NIOOutputStream.write(NIOOutputStream.java:241)
```

Comment: In Oracle support you can check Doc ID 2688428.1

Comment: the Doc ID you mentioned does not help